# Tuberculosis: Lung scarring and weight gain

Tags: medications, infection, disease, infectious-diseases, tuberculosis

I have a few questions regarding tuberculosis:

1. If a person is cured of Tuberculosis, is it compulsory for all patients effected by Tb to have a patch/scar on their lung? (references for patch) 
   [Reference](http://doctor.ndtv.com/faq/ndtv/fid/11738/Why_is_the_x-ray_showing_a_patch_on_the_lungs_after_TB_treatment.html)
2. Can't the patch/scar on the lung ever go away? Or will it stay forever? If it can go away, in what procedure can it be done?
3. One of the references talk about the weight gain. If there is no weight gain, what does that mean?

Comment: i have heard that a patch is formed on the lung wall when attacked by Tb, I dont know the details of the patch...

Comment: @YviDe I have edited the question now, see if you can help

Comment: @YviDe, then I will be asked to give proper citations, which I don't want to re-research on... Please tell whether to write it as an answer, based on experiences, without any citation or not?

Comment: @ABcDexter please write whatever you know....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, it is not compulsory for all the patients to have/develop a scar which is most probably the [pulmonary fibrosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonary_fibrosis) or might be [residual parenchymal lesions](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24670573).

   - In certain cases, it is due to not doing the breathing exercises while taking the standard regime of HREZ (isoniazid, rifampicin, ethambutol, pyrazinamide)
2. Yes, it can get better(not completely removed) with time if the person does variety of [breathing exercises](http://www.livestrong.com/article/327849-controlled-breathing-exercises-for-pulmonary-fibrosis/) like:

   - Yoga (pranayam).
   - Deep breathing, using props like balloons.
   - Aerobics, morning walks, etc.
3. In tuberculosis, weight gain is a healthy indication that the medicines are working. 
    The medicines are given keeping in mind the current weight of the patient. The importance of maintaining a proper BMI(Body Mass Index) is revealed in case studies of relapses. 
   Please read this: [WHO report on TB](http://www.who.int/tb/TBnutrition.pdf)

Comment: Why downvoted ??

Comment: Why do you think pulmonary fibrosis can be caused by not doing breathing exercises, or that breathing exercises can make it go away? Your source says "The scarring is permanent once it has developed."

Comment: @YviDe I never said it can be caused by no doing breathing exercises. It can diminish if one does breathing exercises regularly. That's what my doctor said, and i have no reasons to not believe him (he is much experienced.)

Comment: while you're not saying that pulmonary fibrosis is caused by not doing breathing exercises, you at least say that it could be prevented by doing them. Health.SE has a policy that sources should be provided for statements like that, or that yoga can get rid of pulmonary fibrosis, see: http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers this is likely why your answer got downvoted

Comment: Oh, I see. will take care of this. And, as far as my answer is concerned, I shall provide reliable resource(s).

Comment: @ABcDexter - It's been 2 months, can you update with the references you promised?

Comment: It would be a very good answer if your claim about breathing exercises was supported by a more reliable resource ([this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4085933/) is not a perfect one, since it is a case-study and doesn't involve multiple patients, but it is published in a peer-reviewed journal). Also when you mention physical exercise limitation concerns such as [these](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC461789/) should be discussed.

Comment: @JohnP I added a bit, will be adding more when i get a stable internet connection.

Comment: @Lucky Thank you, I'll be updating with more reliable resources (today only).

Answer (score 2):

*Tuberculosis and scarring*

That scar on the X-rays is likely [a leftover from either a lymphadenopathy or a lung cavity](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0720048X04000890). A lymphadenopathy is a swelling of the lymph nodes and appears in almost all patients, a lung cavity occurs in about half the patients.

Most people [recover from tuberculosis with no further negative effects](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000077.htm), but [some scarring may remain behind in the lungs](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/pulmonary-fibrosis/basics/causes/con-20029091). The scarring you are asking about is likely caused by the lymph nodes:

> The lymphadenopathy usually resolves slower than the pulmonary lesions, with no residual features. The nodes decrease in size after 3 months of treatment, though in some cases a paradoxical, transitory increase in size is seen in the first period of treatment. In one-third of cases, the lung infiltrates leave some kind of **parenchymal scar**, such as a nodule (tuberculoma), which can calcify forming the Ghon focus, or an area of fibrosis.

A parenchymal scar is a scar in the lungs. No surgery is done to remove it.

*Tuberculosis and weight*

Tuberculosis leads to weight loss and malnutrition. Weight *gain* is a positive sign [that a patient is recovering from tuberculosis and the risk of a relapse is small](http://www.who.int/tb/TBnutrition.pdf). Weight *loss* indicates that something is wrong, [for example with the liver](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20875187).